# How to detect actual packet loss by comparing pcap captured on both sides?

Tags: packet-sniffers

Actually i'm trying to evaluate the performance and efficiency of different protocols. I'm aware that TCP implementation considers a packet as "lost" when either the ack timeout or 3 duplicate acks are received. But this cannot tell when the packet is actually lost among the network.

Now i'm capturing packets on both sides of the connection via tcpdump, and get two pcap files. Can i get which exact packets are lost by comparing the two pcap files? And is this worth trying?

A direct attempting would be differing the ip packets' IDs to get the unmatched ones, which is also my first try. The problem is that the network adapter splits and combines some packets so libpcap cannot capture the actual ip packets through the network.

If i don't turn off features such like "generic receive offload" on NIC, which are on by default, what i captured on sender side and receiver side will not match exactly, so simply differing the ids will lead to wrong conclusion; But turning off the features that splitting/combining packets may affect transporting performance badly and thus my conclusion in the other way. So i'm in the middle of a dilemma.

A related post about how "GRO", "LRO" features behave on NIC:
[different tcp packets captured on sender and receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986045/different-tcp-packets-captured-on-sender-and-receiver)

Comment: You could look for PUSH+ACK packets with duplicate sequence numbers, then compare the counts of such packets on each side. That'd tell you how many retransmits really were related to a failure.

Comment: Agree with you on that retransmitions tell which packets need to be "retransmitted" thus must have been "lost". But i'm not quite clear about why "ACK+PSH" can be helpful (why not only ack packets?) and how counting such packets can tell the lost packet? could you be more specific?

Comment: My understanding is that retransmits outside of the handshake are always ACK+PSH, so that'll reduce your computing time for discovering duplicates because you only have to look for duplicates with those flags. Counting them on each side just gives you a way to work out what the total loss count is.

Comment: As long as i can see from wireshark, it is not always "ACK+PSH" outside handshake within a tcp connection. Also if a packets is received after timeout, it is also considered as "lost" and retransmittion happens. How can i tell such lost packet?